# SharePoint site documents storage

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, site, onedrive-for-business, synchronization

I'm using OneDrive for buisness at my university and I use to share files (such as inventories) with my work team. I read about the [two possibilities](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/should-i-save-my-documents-to-onedrive-for-business-or-a-team-site-d18d21a0-1f9f-4f6c-ac45-d52afa0a4a2e): sharing files stored at my own OneDrive space or creating a SharePoint site for everybody. I'm trying the second one after having some synching troubles with the first one...

My question is:  after [moving](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-files-and-folders-between-onedrive-and-sharepoint-5916f90d-f58a-4bf9-b135-10853f516d0b) our shared files to a site (lets say 0.5 TB), are they taking part of my 1 TB storage capacity? Are they taking at the same time 0.5 TB of the capacity of every member? Or more in general, is there any difference in what I (creator) and other members (with full permission) see or "suffer" (like lossing 0.5 TB)?

Answer (score 1):

After you move files from OneDrive to a site, the used storage will take part of the site storage, not your storage or others' storage.

SharePoint Online administrator could set storage limits for site collections and sites.

There is an article which lists storage limits by plan, you can take a look at:
[SharePoint Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)